# Explaining python generator for a long list

Tags: python, oop, data-structures

I am new python programmer,what I have understood so far,"yield" keyword returns an object in lieu of that the generator function returns only the generator object.

so if I have a list which contains 10K items,how I can make smart,pythonic solution without appending values in a list and make it large.

That means,I am appending some values to a list and finally a large list is created like below:

```
def example():
    final_list = []
    for i in range(0,10000):
        final_list.append(i)
    return final_list
```

This is just an example,not a real problem,I used range() just for generating loop nothing else,in my real problem,there are no sequential data,it will be random strings,and the findla list will contain 10K string.
so how can I get all the values without appending to a list in an efficient pythonic manner.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want a generator or a list?

Comment: I think you should edit the question to make it more clear. Also, commas should be followed by whitespace :)

Comment: I do not think the question deserves to be downvoted.  He wrote he is a Python beginner, and it is always difficult to find a good question for beginners.  My +1 to the question ;)  But my +1 also to Niklas B. suggestion to edit/improve the question.  Making question clear for yourself makes also easier to understand the solution later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> I am getting some string after crawling a web page and appending those
>   string to a list,as the crawler geting large data,the list is getting
>   bigger,finally when I want to iterate the list,its time and memory
>   consuming

So:

```
# generator function to crawl web pages
def crawler():
    while iStillHaveWebPagesToCrawl():
        someStrings = getSomeStringsFromAWebPage()
        for aString in someStrings:
            yield aString

def oneStringAtATime():
    for aString in crawler():
        doSomethingWith( aString )
```

When you call `oneStringAtATime()`, it sets up the generator function called `crawler()`; each time `crawler()` executes `yield`, the loop in `oneStringAtATime()` iterates once with that string. When `crawler()` runs out of web pages and exits the function, the `oneStringAtATime()` loop exits.

Answer (score 5):

Your example is over simplified, so let's pretend you wanted 10000 random numbers instead.

There are two ways to create a generator. One is with the `yield` statement:

```
def example():
    for i in xrange(10000):
        yield random.random()
```

The other way is with a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
(random.random() for i in xrange(10000))
```

Which one you choose will depend on your code complexity.

Comment: Briefly explained,I am getting some string after crawling a web page and appending those string to a list,as the crawler geting large data,the list is getting bigger,finally when I want to iterate the list,its time and memory consuming.

Comment: @arnold: You can use a generator for that, but maybe you might want to have separate threads, one for crawling and one for processing?

Comment: @arnold, a generator can't help with the time but it can help with the memory. The full list never exists in memory, but each element is generated as it is needed (thus the name `generator`).

Comment: @MarkRansom how generator can be implemented in my case?

Comment: @arnold, in the place where you would append the result to a list, use a yield instead.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you well, then you use the `range(0, 10000)` only to simulate the sequence.  Whenever you use the `yield` in a function definition, it becomes a *generator function*.  When generator function is used (called), it returns iterator -- you do not see it. Try the following `gen()` instead:

```
def gen(n):
    while n > 0:
        yield n
        n -= 1    # decrement the value
```

Then you typically use it in a loop:

```
for x in gen(10000):
    print x,         # comma to suppress new line
```

If you have a function that returns your strings, just `yield s` instead of building the list.  Then call the generator function and collect only the values that you want (here not strings but numbers divisible by 100):

```
lst = []   # init
for x in gen(10000):
    if x % 100 == 0:
        lst.append(x)
print lst
```

The loop can be also replaced by so called list comprehension:

```
lst = [ x for x in gen(10000) if x % 100 == 0 ]
print lst
```

...which is more understandable (i.e. resembles the above loop) when you write the same like that:

```
lst = [ x 
        for x in gen(10000) 
            if x % 100 == 0 ]
print lst
```

But you can use a generator function wherever a sequence is expected. If your generator can implement the decision whether your element is to be collected, then you can simply make a list of the produced elements like this:

```
lst = list(gen(100))
print lst
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from reading the question/looking at the OP code and some of the comments below it looks like OP is working with a list.

So,

```
def example():
    final_list = range(0, 10000) # or xrange() for v 2.x
    return final_list
```

could probably do w/o the temporary final_list variable too, but left for clarity.

If the values of the list are something other than the series generated by range/xrange then [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is suitable here.

Still feel the question is a bit unclear.

Comment: This is really pointless - `(i for i in x)` is utterly pointless (it does nothing in this case, and could be replaced in any case with `iter(x)`) - range will still generate the list first in 2.x, and in 3.x this will do nothing.

Comment: @Lattyware I understand the comment re 2.x - but can you expand on 3.x? Are you saying just using range(0, 10000) by itself would be sufficient? I agree, the `i for i` is useless in this case .. force of habit :-/

Comment: In 3.x, [`range()` returns a generator anyway](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#range).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> xrange_object = xrange(10000)
>>> xrange_object[0]
0
>>> xrange_object[1]
1
```

I see that you've edited your question. If you have a random string generating function, `ran_string`, you could use a generator expression to do what you want, like this:

```
>>> final_gen = (ran_string(i) for i in xrange(10000))
```

Comment: @NiklasB. I think the issue is people interpreting the asker's (very unclear) question differently. (Just to be clear, I did *not* downvote.)

Comment: Here random means anonymous data,the data actually scraped from several sites,appending into a list.which lists is a very big one

Comment: @Lattyware: I think *you* are misinterpreting the question. To me it looks like OP actually *wants* a generator. Sorry, but it's just not clear what's meant

Answer (score 0):

You were not very clear in your question - what you are looking for here is a [generator expression](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY).

E.g:

```
>>> values = (random.random() for _ in range(10))
>>> for value in values:
...     print(value)
... 
0.32161489939829857
0.285715480204797
0.4961165128957876
0.42658612656828354
0.5083396364418685
0.00843781669361321
0.49698036590463757
0.8067300769956716
0.5741614069287628
0.4728079544997392
```

If you want to then iterate over the values you have you can use a generator expression to generate values based on the existing iterable, without constructing a list up front. They are generated as they are requested (in this case, when the loop requests them).

Check the video linked above for a deeper explanation of the syntax of generator expressions (and all it's cousins, list comps, set comps, etc...).

Comment: This *will* create a list. I think OP wants to prevent that.

Comment: @NiklasB. I think that's what the OP wants - if you ignore the talk of generators at the start, and read the second half, he appears to want to 'construct a list without appending' - so I think he is looking for a list comprehension. It's hard to tell.

Comment: It's "avoid appending to a list", not "creating a list without appending". I think "without appending values in a list and make it large" means that OP doesn't want to create a temporary list at all.

Comment: @NiklasB. I think you are right, reading again, I've updated my response to suit.

Comment: @Lattyware nice video on list comprehension, do you have one in the works for generators (sorry for the slightly off-topic comment)

Comment: @Levon I didn't, but I might well do one.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but I'll assume that what you mean is that you want an object you can iterate over but which is lazy - i.e. doesn't precalculate and store all values.

```
def example():
    for i in xrange(10000):
        yield i

g = example()
print g.next() # prints '0'
print g.next() # prints '1'
for x in g:
    print x # prints '2', '3', ..., '10000'
```

I've used xrange in the example since using range would kind of defeat the purpose, obviously you can put whatever you want in the function.  The way it works is that g will remember it's internal state (in this case the value of i) and run until the next yield statement each time you call g.next() or iterate over g.

I hope that helps!